# counting android app using with SharePrefrence and doesn't initialize sharePrefrence

Tags: android, null, sharedpreferences

I want to create in-app-purchasing duo to control times of using my app with `SharedPreferences`. 
I have  3 activities:

- FirstActivity - shows just at the first time
- MainActivity
- MyketActivity-- include `SharedPreferences` and in-app-purchasing code

`FirstActivity` shows just at the first time of app running and `myket.getLogginTime(1)` (`loggin_time_SharePrefrence` saves `1` time). 
next time, app runs from `MainActivity` and `myket.getLogginTime(1)` (`loggin_time_SharePrefrence` saves `2` time).
 finally the TIME checks with `checkLogginTime`.

but as I run my app,it crashed in FirstActivity and showed me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void getLogginTime(int)' on a null object reference
                  at myketActivity.java
```

in FirstActivity.java:

```
  public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
         public MyketActivity myketActivity = new MyketActivity();
...

    myketActivity.getLogginTime(1); // this is the first time
}
```

in MyketActivity.class:

```
public class MyketActivity extends Activity {
public static SharedPreferences loggin_time_SharePrefrence;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor_logginTimer;
private int times_of_getting_premium = 2;
public static final int loggin_time=0;
public BackDialog purchaseDialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myket);

    //in app purchasing
    loggin_time_SharePrefrence = getSharedPreferences("times", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor_logginTimer = loggin_time_SharePrefrence.edit();


     //loggin_time=loggin_time_SharePrefrence.getInt("times",loggin_time);
...
       }//on create
public void getLogginTime (int i){
    editor_logginTimer.putInt("times",i).commit();
}

public int checkLogginTime(){
   int t= loggin_time_SharePrefrence.getInt("times",loggin_time);
    return t;
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: obviously onCreate is not called ... obviously because (and asked bazillion times) you should not use `operator new` with `Activity` (`Service` / `Application`) derived classes

Answer (score 0):

- ohh you need to intialize SharedPreferences before try to get data,
  like this

  ```
          `SharedPreferences loggin_time_SharePrefrence = new loggin_time_SharePrefrence (MainActivity.this);`
  ```
- now  u can get your data // suppose u want to get data of name in
  string for that

  `String name= loggin_time_SharePrefrence.getString("name");`

Comment: i do it with `loggin_time_SharePrefrence = getSharedPreferences("times", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`. i did it too previously, but this time...